# Please mark my question as Community Wiki

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question, community-wiki

I've been developing Nokia S40 webapps for about 3 months. During this time, I've struggling with how to code in it. Because, there are non existence tutorials on it. Because it's not published at that time.

Now that Nokia [decided it's time to open it](http://blogs.forum.nokia.com/blog/nokia-developer-news/2011/05/26/ovi-store-open-for-series-40-web-apps). I've created [new question on SO just for storing tips and trick when developing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150184/nokia-s40-ovi-browser-web-app-tips-trick) (that I find useful).

My request is to mark it as Community Wiki so that more and more people contribute to it.
In time, I'm sure it will generate HUGE traffic to SO (particularly from developing country, where S40 is king in those area).

Answer (score 5):

Just flag your own question for moderator attention and ask for it to be CW'd in the "Other" box.

Answer (score 1):

You should phrase it in a different manner, to make it more as a wiki, not like "now that X has happened, we should do more Y" but "What are some tips and trick when using X?"